# Kaspersky marks an URL on my site as phishing?

Tags: php, http-headers, phishing

I've recently finished a website for a client which is using some ajax-calls. At some point a local virus scanner Kaspersky is saying the url `www.domain.com/ajax/ajax.php?Request=request-to-perform` is a phishing URL. Obviously it's not.

Any of you guys ran in to this before? Can I set some headers to tell Kaspersky to relax? There doesn't seem to be much helpful information around.

Thanks in advance for your reply.

Answer (score 0):

Please, try to report about the false-positive alarm via http://newvirus.kaspersky.com otherwise you can report about the problem via https://my.kaspersky.com.